# C# calculator exponet function. How?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a calculator for a school project.
I need to have an exponent function, but can't figure out how. I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double?' to 'double'

some of my code.

```
namespace Lommeregner
{
    public partial class Lommeregner : Form
    {
        double? firstpressednumber;
        double sum;
        double? secondpressednumber = null;
        string operationclicked;

        onscreenShower _onscreenShower = new onscreenShower();
```

My exponent:

```
private void btn_exponent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            screen_text.Text = _onscreenShower.DisplayOnScreen(Math.Exp(secondpressednumber).ToString(), screen_text.Text.ToString());
        }
```

My equal code.

```
private void btn_equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(screen_text.ToString().Length>0)
            {
                switch(operationclicked)
                {
                    case "+":
                        secondpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());
                        sum = double.Parse((firstpressednumber + secondpressednumber).ToString());
                        firstpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());

                        screen_text.Text = sum.ToString();
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        secondpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());
                        sum = double.Parse((firstpressednumber - secondpressednumber).ToString());
                        firstpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());

                        screen_text.Text = sum.ToString();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        secondpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());
                        sum = double.Parse((firstpressednumber * secondpressednumber).ToString());
                        firstpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());

                        screen_text.Text = sum.ToString();
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        secondpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());
                        sum = double.Parse((firstpressednumber / secondpressednumber).ToString());
                        firstpressednumber = double.Parse(screen_text.Text.ToString());

                        screen_text.Text = sum.ToString();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Try `Math.Exp(secondpressednumber.Value)`, note it will throw an exception if `secondpressednumber` is `null` so maybe check for that first.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton I know the reason why, that's why I made that suggestion.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton I meant `secondpressednumber.Value` will throw an exception if `secondpressednumber` is null, not if you pass a `double?` to `Math.Exp`.

Comment: @juharr I see what you mean now; I thought you were telling the OP that simply passing in `secondpressednumber` itself would give an exception if it was null. Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet today...

Answer (score 2):

Your double is **nullable**

If you want to access its value, try `doubleVarName.Value`

You can check if it has a value using `doubleVarName.HasValue` then pass the value to your method if true

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.Exp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.exp(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a `double` as the parameter - you're (trying to) pass it a nullable double (`double?`).

At minimum you want the `.Value`, but you almost certainly should be checking a value exists first:

```
if(!secondpressednumber.HasValue)
   throw new InvalidOperationException("No value");
screen_text.Text = _onscreenShower.DisplayOnScreen(Math.Exp(secondpressednumber.Value).ToString(), screen_text.Text.ToString());
```